# SearchBox result suggestion Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I got a strange issue with my searchBox in Windows 8.1 App.

I got an unhandler exception (and a crush) if in my Suggestion i do not append the querySuggestion and append only the ResultSuggestion.

the problem occurs when i change the queryText.

This is my function

```
public async void OnSuggest(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox e, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

        var queryText = args.QueryText != null ? args.QueryText.Trim() : null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryText)) return;

        TransporterExt tr_search = new TransporterExt();
        tr_search.name = queryText;


        try
        {



            var suggestionCollection = args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection;
            ObservableCollection<TransporterExt> querySuggestions = await TransporterService.Search(tr_search);


            if (querySuggestions != null && querySuggestions.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (TransporterExt tr in querySuggestions)
                {

                    //if (tr.name.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(e.QueryText.ToUpperInvariant()))
                    //{
                    //    //suggestionCollection.AppendQuerySuggestion(tr.name);
                    //    suggestionCollection.AppendResultSuggestion(tr.name,
                    //                                                 tr.trId.ToString(),
                    //                                                 tr.trId.ToString(),
                    //                                                 imgRef, "imgDesc");


                    //}
                    suggestionCollection.AppendQuerySuggestion(tr.name);


                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Ignore any exceptions that occur trying to find search suggestions.
        }

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

I got the searchBox inside an UserControl

My controller code

```
public delegate void SuggestionsRequested(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args);

    public event Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler<Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs> SearchBoxSuggestionsRequested;

    private void SearchBoxSuggestions(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {

         if (SearchBoxSuggestionsRequested != null)
            SearchBoxSuggestionsRequested(sender, args);


    }
```

I got this exception

WinRT: A method was called at an unexpected time.
exception: System.InvalidOperationException - type (string)

> Edited Solution - Working function

First of all i remove from the constructor of the page the registration of event

```
public TruckCrudPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;

        //this.truckForm.SearchBoxSuggestionsRequested += OnSuggest;
    }

public async void OnSuggest(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox e, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
        TransporterExt tr_search = new TransporterExt();
        ObservableCollection<TransporterExt> querySuggestions = new ObservableCollection<TransporterExt>();
        var queryText = args.QueryText != null ? args.QueryText.Trim() : null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryText)) return;

        suggested.Clear();

        tr_search.name = queryText;
        try
        {


            var suggestionCollection = args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection;


             querySuggestions = await TransporterService.Search(tr_search);    



            if (querySuggestions != null && querySuggestions.Count > 0 )

             {

                 int i = 0;
                 foreach (TransporterExt tr in querySuggestions)
                 {
                     if (tr.name.StartsWith(e.QueryText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                     //if (tr.name.ToLower().Contains(e.QueryText))
                     {
                         string name = tr.name;
                         string detail = tr.trId.ToString(); 
                         string tag = i.ToString(); 
                         string imageAlternate = "imgDesc";

                         suggestionCollection.AppendResultSuggestion(name, detail, tag, imgRef, imageAlternate);

                         suggested.Add(tr);
                         //Debug.WriteLine("dentro" + suggested.Count);
                         i++;
                     }


               }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //Ignore any exceptions that occur trying to find search suggestions.
             Debug.WriteLine("Exception generata " + exc.Message);
             Debug.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
        }

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

But it works only with condition StartsWith and i would like to use Contains

Comment: When the unhandler  is fire?

Comment: when is called SuggestionCollection.AppendResultSuggestion

Comment: Maybe a problem with query. Query got a value or iy's null?

Comment: i edited the code, to check better, i got a problem even if i call the AppendQuerySuggestion, the query got values, but i check if there's almost one element

Comment: my debugger says WinRT: A method was called at an unexpected time.

Comment: hummm,var suggestionCollection = args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection; suggestionCollection is null?

Comment: Try catch suggestionCollection.AppendQuerySuggestion(tr.name); and say me the error please

Comment: A method was called at an unexpected time. exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: And tr.name value is what when error is fire?

Comment: tr.name is correct when is fired. is not null, and properly initialized

Comment: @MatDev8 i think i found the problem. In the constructor page, i registered the SearchBox SuggestsRequestEvent...removing that all works this is what i removed:  `searchbox.SearchBoxSuggestionsRequested += OnSuggest;` ... if u can take again a look to my code, i got a problem again, now it works only if the string strarts with the textQuery field, but i would like to search something like contains

Answer (score 2):

You can use SearchBox and SuggestionRequested event to fire the event when type on the SearchBox. I will show an Example

```
<SearchBox x:Name="SearchBoxSuggestions" SuggestionsRequested="SearchBoxEventsSuggestionsRequested"/>
```

and write the SearchBoxEventsSuggestionsRequested handler in the code behind

```
    private void SearchBoxEventsSuggestionsRequested(object sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        string queryText = e.QueryText;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryText))
        {
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchSuggestionCollection suggestionCollection = e.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection;
            foreach (string suggestion in SuggestionList)
            {
                if (suggestion.StartsWith(queryText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    suggestionCollection.AppendQuerySuggestion(suggestion);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

You can add the keyword to **SuggestioList**,  and it will show in the dropdown when you type on the Searchbox.

Create the SuggestionList

```
public List<string> SuggestionList { get; set; }
```

initialize the list

```
SuggestionList = new List<string>();
```

and add keywords to the list

```
SuggestionList.Add("suggestion1");
SuggestionList.Add("suggestion2");
SuggestionList.Add("suggestion3");
SuggestionList.Add("suggestion4");
SuggestionList.Add("Fruits");
```

When you type s on the Searchbox it will show all the keyword starts with s.

Thanks.